# Extracting Episodes

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hey I want to extract content from [this site](https://gogohd.net/download?id=MTA2MjQ=&token=YHkJA3pQ-GEZzolNgmnxOw&expires=1677315733) using python, but I need content of 1 div and the div is showing but the content inside div is not showing

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req = requests.get("https://gogohd.net/download?id=MTA2MjQ=&token=fU0FFpfwZ8OMWSbHJ11VQg&expires=1677243941")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
div_bs4 = soup.findAll('div')
print(div_bs4)
```

And output is

```
</div>, <div class="clr" id="content-download">
```

In website content in showing in the div with class clr but at the time of extraction it's not showing

So please help me with it and I have not given the full output because its too lengthy

I was trying to extract the episodes and thought it will give me the episode

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50612469/15923186 Your page is empty, cause the JS hasn't populated the DOM when the python script was trying to extract the content. Also format code as code and...please do some research before asking a question on SO. Cheers!

Comment: *selenium* would be a good choice for this